# Can you set a font at 11,5?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I tried `\documentclass[11,5pt]{book}`, but received `LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [11,5pt].`

Comment: As a note: `scrbook` would allow arbitrary font sizes with `\documentclass[fontsize=11.5pt]{scrbook}`. Note however that you need a scalable font in order to use arbitraty font sizes (either way).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a font of that size `\fontsize{11.5}{12}\selectfont` but the options to book are not lengths they are just names of options and there are just three that look a bit like lengths: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, and they do a lot more than set a font size they set the page size, the size of all the named sizes etc.

Comment: I'm getting plenty of `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <11.5> not available (Font) size <12> substituted on input line 156.` I think I'll settle for 12pt finally. My fonts dont support it as Skillmon said

Comment: add `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` @alfred It is rather unlikely that you are not using scalable fonts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why `RequirePackage`? alfred isn't writing a class. `usepackage` is the convention for user documents, isn't it?

Comment: @JAB: The fix-cm documentation says to load it before `\documentclass` and using `\RequirePackage`, because "If the package is loaded in the preamble, a preceding package or even the code of the document class may have used any of the CM fonts already. However, the definitions of those fonts, that are already in use, cannot be changed any more."

Answer (score 3):

1. Not all parsers understand 11,5 (with comma) to mean 11.5 (with period). EDIT: In general, it is a matter of choosing a language setting.
2. If your book is general writing (not math), consider the "novel" document class. Since it uses LuaLaTeX with fontspec, you can easily choose a decimal font size using Open Type fonts.

Comment: (1) seems false or at least confusing, parsers of other languages may or may not allow a decimal comma depending on the language, but surely any tex parser will be able to parse tex. and so `\fontsize{11,5}{12,5}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Agreed that my comment was unclear.

Comment: You can edit it:-)

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but relatively new package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fix-cm}% if you use the default fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[fontsize=11.5pt]{fontsize}

\begin{document}

This is in 11.5pt size: \makeatletter\f@size\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked for the font size but it screwed up the formatting - indentations and paragraph spacing - of my other text. Can I suppress these other side effects somehow?

Comment: @RS06 This answers the question for a whole document at that size.